# Replace last valid index with specific value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm working on a data frame that has one hot encoded columns. For simplicity, let's say it looks like this:

```
    a   b
0   1 NaN
1   1   1
2   1 NaN
3 NaN   1
```

I want to replace the last available value with NaN. I'm getting the last available index location with

```
df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

Out[6]:
a    2
b    3
```

So using that, I wanted to use

```
df.replace(df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index), np.nan)
```

This doesn't seem to replace the last valid index cell with NaN. Does anyone have a good idea of how to replace the last value with NaN or any other value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.values` with `get_indexer`

```
s=df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

df.values[df.index.get_indexer(s),df.columns.get_indexer(s.index.tolist())]=99999
df
         a        b
0      1.0      NaN
1      1.0      1.0
2  99999.0      NaN
3      NaN  99999.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the idxmax on the reversed DataFrame:

```
In [11]: pd.notnull(df[::-1]).idxmax()
Out[11]:
a    2
b    3
dtype: int64
```

---

To set these to NaN you could use a for loop:

```
for c, i in pd.notnull(df[::-1]).idxmax().items():
    df.at[i, c] = np.nan
```

Comment: Using this still doesn't help with the replacement of that value to NaN

Comment: @codingenthusiast added method to do that, I think there ought to be a better way...

Comment: Hi Sir , maybe you can change to `at`